# Intercept a Python server client connection

Tags: python, sockets

I have programed a simple client server connection that uses TCP to communicate this is the client portion of the code:

```
import socket
import time
import random

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 60000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
Message = ["Password place holder, ", "Testing waiting, ", "There is only Zuul, ", "panic at the disco"]

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
for string in Message:
    sock.send(string)
    value = random.randint(20,40)
    time_end = time.time() + value
    i = 0
    while time.time() < time_end:
        i = i+1


data = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
sock.close()

print ("recieved data: ", data)
```

and this the server portion of the code:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 60000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
sock.listen(1)

conn, address = sock.accept()
print('Connection address: ', address)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data : break 
    print("Recieved data: ", data)
    conn.send(data)
conn.close
```

What I want to know is there a way to design a script that can intercept or read the data being sent between these two programs?

Comment: why would you need this script? what is your requirement?

Comment: Developing a sort of exercise.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what tcpdump (and wireshark) do. In another window on the same box, run `sudo tcpdump -i lo -w /tmp/lo.pcap`. (`lo` is the loopback interface on your machine, and corresponds to the address `127.0.0.1`). This will capture all the packets sent on behalf of the two programs.